# Where is the fulltext search data in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, full-text-catalog

I create a fulltext index on a table,I want to have a look at the fulltext data after the population.Is there a file contains fulltext index information?  Where is it? Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, you can specify a filegroup where the index will be stored. This option isn’t available in SQL Server 2005 because filegroup association is at the catalog level.
That means you can issue a query that lists the contents of the index on SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT display_term, column_id, document_count 

FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords 

  (DB_ID('AdventureWorks2008'), OBJECT_ID('ProductDocs'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run **sp_help_fulltext_columns** you will get the Fulltext index tables and columns 
in the database.